# Powershell Replace quoted text in multiple files

Tags: regex

In order to sync a file to our ECM server, I need to scan a metadata file which contains the following lines:

```
  <data-items>
   <item type="primary" id="OLL5638" module="PY" descriptor="Payroll">
      <description>Leave Application Number - 1234</description>
    </item>
    <item type="secondary" id="123" module="PY" descriptor="Payroll">
      <description>Joe Bloggs</description>
    </item>
    <item type="secondary" id="123" module="PY" descriptor="Payroll">
      <description>Joe Bloggs</description>
    </item>
```

I need to change the PRIMARY line so that it forces a 'docloader' process to fail on the PRIMARY item and then attempt to sync the file using the SECONDARY item instead.

My PS1 file is as follows

```
$Path = "C\Temp\Tester\*.METADATA"
$SearchStr = <item type="primary" id="([A-Z]*\d*)" module="PY" descriptor="Testing">
$ReplTxt = <item type="primary" id="$1" module="PY" descriptor="Testing">
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path |
foreach{
(Get-Content $_ | foreach {$_ -replace $SearchStr, $ReplTxt)} | Set-Content $_ }
```

I have tried with all the following and am still not getting it to work.

**DOUBLE QUOTES**

$SearchStr = ""
$ReplTxt = ""

**SINGLE QUOTES**

$SearchStr = ''
$ReplTxt = ''

**REGEX ESCAPE**

[Regex]::escape($SearchStr = )
[Regex]::escape($ReplTxt = )

REGEX ESCAPE with Single Quotes
[Regex]::escape($SearchStr = '')
[Regex]::escape($ReplTxt = '')

REGEX ESCAPE with Double Quotes
[Regex]::escape($SearchStr = <"item type="primary" id="([A-Z]*\d*)" module="PY" descriptor="Testing">")
[Regex]::escape("$ReplTxt = ")

**MANUAL ESCAPES** - (I have tried with combos of single and double quotes too)
eg: insert a backslash before any Double Quote

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple variants for escape characters in Windows, depending on the used functions cf https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

In PowerShell the escape character for `"` is the backtick **`** (the one used here to mark inline code), see https://serverfault.com/questions/47811/what-is-the-literal-escape-character-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ralph. The links were able to point me in the right direction.

If I exclude the '<' and '>' and just search for:

```
'item type="primary" id="([A-Z]*\d*)" module="PY" descriptor="Payroll"'
```

By using the regex ([A-Z]*\d*) instead of the 'OLL5638' (which I originally quoted),   I this makes my script dynamic so that I can update multiple files in a folder(s).
and replace with:

```
'item type="primary" id="$1" module="PY" descriptor="TESTING"'
```

So my final script is

```
$Path = "C:\Temp\Tester"
$FindTxt =  'item type="primary" id="([A-Z]*\d*)" module="PY" descriptor="Payroll"'
$ReplTxt = 'item type="primary" id="$1" module="PY" descriptor="TESTING"'

write-Output "__________ Processing.... ________________"
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.METADATA" |
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |
ForEach-Object {
    If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $FindTxt) {
        write-Output $_.FullName
        (Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace $FindTxt, $ReplTxt | Set-Content  $_.FullName
        }
    }
pause
```